# Using timers for the first time in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to work out why my code is not working, basically I am creating a clicker game, and every time I run the code in VB 2017, and then purchase the upgrade, the money doesn't update automatically. I am confused, and getting rather annoyed that I am incapable of something that would seem so basic, although I am new-ish to VB. Can anyone shed light on what I am doing incorrectly?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim money As Decimal = 2000
    Dim LevelMultiplier As Decimal = 1
    Dim Price1 As Integer = 75
    Dim LevelCount As Integer = 1
    Dim AutoPrice1 As Integer = 1500



    Private Sub label_avail_money_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles label_avail_money.TextChanged
        label_avail_money.Text = Math.Round(money, 2).ToString("0.00")
        If money >= AutoPrice1 Then
            Button3.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen

        Else
            Button3.BackColor = Color.Gray
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        money = money + (1 * LevelMultiplier)
        If money >= Price1 Then
            Button2.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen

        Else
            Button2.BackColor = Color.Gray
        End If
        label_avail_money.Text = money
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If money >= Price1 Then
            money = money - Price1
            LevelCount = LevelCount + 1
            LevelMultiplier = LevelMultiplier * 1.1
            Price1 = Price1 * 1.25
            lblPrice1.Text = Math.Round(Price1, 2).ToString("0.00")
        Else
            MsgBox("Insufficient Funds")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        money = money + 1
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If money >= AutoPrice1 Then
            Timer1.Start()
            money = money - AutoPrice1


        Else
            MsgBox("Insufficient Funds")
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: The issue is that the timer when run, it actually doesn't display the money being added to the total. Which I am really confused about. I believe it does do it, because it seems to add random amounts of numbers after I click a button and it will update. But I want it to update as soon as the tick occurs.

Comment: The Timer just adds to a variable, it doesn't display anything. If you want to show the new amount, do what you have done in `Button2`: format and display the result. BTW, move `label_avail_money.Text = Math.Round(money, 2).ToString("0.00")` to the `Button1` handler: you don't change the Text of a Control in its `TextChanged` event. Also, use `ToString("N2")` to format the output.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the N2, that actually makes things neater for me, although when I put the text into Button1, the layout I have isn't what I want, however for the others it updates when I click for this I want it to update instantly, not when the button is pressed. That is the issue. Not too sure if I get what you are saying entirely, to do what I have done for Button2

Comment: In `Button2` you are formatting the output, setting the Text of a Label. Do the same in the Timer.Tick event. Btw, you can also format using `"C2"`, this will add the currency symbol to the value, if needed (the Currency symbol is determined by `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. You can set it to any available culture. e.g., `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`).

Comment: @Jimi, I cannot thank you enough I am genuinely so happy right now! Once again, thank you. Have a great day! Can I commend you in anyway? New to the website. :)

Comment: Don't worry about it. You could post an answer yourself, describing the solution adopted. So you'll get some experience in this department, too :) (Btw, the `2` in `C2`, `N2` means *2 decimal places*. You can specify a different value, e.g., `"C3"`, `"N10"` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The *Timer* just adds to a variable, it doesn't display anything. If you want to show the new amount, do what you have done in Button2: format and display the result.

BTW, move `label_avail_money.Text = Math.Round(money, 2).ToString("0.00")` to the Button1 handler: you don't change the *.Text of a Control* in its `TextChanged Event`. Also, use `.ToString("N2")` to format the output.

- Credit to @Jimi for finding the solution!